# creating a user_id index rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, userid

how do I create a user_id column for mapping the id of one databse index to another?

I am aware of has_many & belongs_to, but I wan't sure if I needed to specify user_id when creating the model ...

```
rails g model User name:string email:string
```

`rails g model Card inputA:string inputB:string` -- do I add `user_id:integer` ?

and then add `has_many :cards`, and `belongs_to :user` ?

or does rails automatically do this when you sue `has_many` and `belongs_to`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you add `user_id:integer` , because the info is needed for the migration which is independent from the models.

what you've proposed there is correct.

Comment: if I needed to add it after creating the model, how would I then create a new migration and then add it?

Comment: `rails g migration add_user_id_to_cards`. then open that migration file and add `add_column(:cards, :user_id, :integer)` to the up, and `remove_column(:cards, :user_id)` to the down

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to do a migration for this, but rather to get to learn how Rails handle building associations between models (that's why I posted the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

What Isotope said is that you need to add a column to the existing model Card. There is an easy way to do this in rails, simply generate a migration that add a column to your model using:

```
rails generate migration add_UserID_to_cards userID:integer
```

The migration file will then look like this:

```
class AddUserIDToCard < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :cards, :userID, :integer
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :cards, :userID
  end
end
```

BUT ... Normally each user has already a unique ID in your database, so I don't think doing this is necessary. Instead, if you build your cards from the users, the link will be done automatically.Ie, in the create method of your card controller:

```
@card = current_user.cards.build(params[:card])
```

It's a complete topic, I suggest to have a look there to start with: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
otherwise, the Hartl tutorial "The Rails 3 tutorial" provides a complete exemple in the last chapters of the book (when it links microposts to users).

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
@card = current_user.cards.build(params[:card])
```

worked perfectly for me. I had an issue of my user_id not being indexed automatically.